# Is there a way to connect a new lambda function an existing AWS ApiGateway using AWS-CDK? (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to wrap my head around AWS-CDK to deploy Lambda functions to aws through it. I already have a pre-existing Api gateway, that I have manually deployed through the console and would like to know if there is any means to connect it as a trigger to new lambda functions deployed using the CDK? I have read through the example code:

```
apigw.LambdaRestApi(
            self, 'Endpoint',
            handler=my_lambda,
        )
```

This creates a new gateway in aws, which is not the functionality that I am looking for.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/LambdaRestApi.html#lambdarestapi

Comment: @balderman Thank you for the quick reply, I have been through that as well before posting here, could you point me to any code snippets or samples that have implemented it?

Comment: sorry - I am not aware of any example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
import * as apigateway from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway';

class BindApiFunctionStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const restapi = apigateway.RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(this, "myapi", {
            restApiId : "<yourrestapiid>",
            rootResourceId : "<yourrootresourceid>"
        });

        const helloWorld = new lambda.Function(this, "hello", {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
            handler: 'index.handler',
            code: lambda.Code.fromInline('exports.handler = function(event, ctx, cb) { return cb(null, "hi"); }')
        })

        restapi.root.addResource("test").addMethod("GET", new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(helloWorld))
    }

}

const app = new cdk.App();
new BindApiFunctionStack(app, 'MyStack');

app.synth();
```

Comment: Can someone tell me, where can I find restApiId and rootResourceId?)

Answer (score 0):

For those unsure as to where `restApiId` and `rootResourceId` are found:

restApiId: The ID of the existing API Gateway REST API.

rootResourceId: The ID of the root resource of the existing API Gateway REST API.

```js
// Create a new API Gateway REST API
const restApi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'MyRestApi', {
  restApiName: 'MyRestApi'
});

const yourrestapiid = restApi.restApiId;
const yourrootresourceid = restApi.restApiRootResourceId;

// Store this as an SSM parameter, etc. to retrieve in another repository
```

Edit: alternatively use the `apigateway.RestApi.fromRestApiId` method.